# Editing Shopify's Checkout

Tags: html, shopify, checkout

So I have recently added a piece of code ( * { text-transform: lowercase !important; } ) to my themes.scss.liquid file to make all the text on my store lowercase.

However, the checkout does not get effected by this script. Is there a way I could use this code in the "Additional scripts" section of the checkout? I have tried multiple methods but none have worked.

It's really annoying as my customers will see the lowercase text and once they go to checkout they'll be presented with text that's not formatted the same.

As it would not be congruent I may lose customers at the checkout.

If anyone can help that would be great. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the checkout code (liquid/css/js) only if you have a Shopify Plus account.

The Additional Scripts apply only on the Thank you page ( the last step of the checkout ) that handles analytics scripts in most cases.

So the short answer is if you have a Plus account - Yes, if you don't have a Plus account - No.

Comment: So there's no way for me to add the same code as I already used (or different) to make the checkout lowercase? I have an intensive script already installed which edits the checkout but I've tried implementing the code into that script and it doesn't work.

Comment: No way without a PLUS account. The only checkout options are from the settings panel where you can change same base predefined options and from the customize panel where you can add/choose a logo/color/font etc...